# Visual Studio 2010 Database Project: Generate DROP statements for objects that are in the target database

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I really like the 'Generate DROP statements for objects that are in the target database' option in the deploy settings; however, we have many different databases.  Each database contains different logins.  How can I still generate DROP statements but ignore logins?